# Não consigo apagar o input de uma JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

Eu estou fazendo um programa e ele utiliza alguns JTextFields formatados, isto é, JFormatedTextField que chama um MaskFormatter. O problema é que, ao  escrever uma mensagem e tentar apaga-la, a mensagem volta, tornando impossível deixar o campo vazio novamente. Alguém tem alguma solução para isto? Aqui o código que estou utilizando:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class NewScheduleWindow extends JFrame{

JTextField hourField = new JTextField();

public NewScheduleWindow(){

    try {
        hourField = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("##:##"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    add(hourField);
    hourField.setBounds(160, 65, 42, 25);
    hourField.setFont(Reference.setDefaultFont(15));
    hourField.requestFocus();

    //Etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada [nesse artigo](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48652.html).

O autor implementa um `AllowBlankMaskFormatter` feito para esse tipo de situação.

```
AllowBlankMaskFormatter abmf = new AllowBlankMaskFormatter("##:##");
ambf.setAllowBlankField(true);
hourField = new JFormattedTextField(abmf);
```

---

Outra alternativa (conforme [essa questão no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825514/values-not-clearing-in-jformattedtextfield)) é setar a política em caso de perda de foco para `COMMIT`:

```
hourField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);
```

Isso vai deixar o valor em branco "inválido" visível.

Você pode então chamar o método [`commitEdit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#commitEdit--) manualmente e, em caso de exceção, resetar o valor para nulo:

```
try {
    hourField.commitEdit();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // qualquer edição inválida reseta o valor
    // você pode também checar apenas pelo pattern padrão de campo vazio
    hourField.setValue(null);
}
```

Não gosto dessa segunda solução por uma série de motivos (uso de exceções em fluxo comum, exibição de valores inválidos, quebrar o princípio do mínimo conhecimento, etc). Recomendo a primeira solução.